# Only layout template being rendered in local environment

Tags: templating, multi-environment

I've just set up a multi-environment install of Craft but am having an issue on my local install under MAMP Pro. Everything seems to be loading fine except for my index template in the root of the 'templates' directory. It extends a `_layout.twig` template but when I load the site locally, only the layout template is being rendered (ie. my block overrides in the index template that extends it aren't being rendered).

However, this works fine on the remote version of the install.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated as I'm scratching my head at this point...

Thanks.

**Update** - here is the code from `_layout.twig` and `index.twig`. Pretty straight forward - and these do work expected in the other non-local environment.

**_layout.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    {% block head %}
        ...head code in here
    {% endblock %}


</head>

<body>

    {% block bodyContent %}
        ...presentational code in here
    {% endblock %}

    {% block footer %}
        ...presentational code in here
    {% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

**index.twig**

```
{% extends "_layout.twig" %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('homepage') %}

{% block head %}
    {{ parent() }}

    ...additional head code
{% endblock %}

{% block bodyContent %}
    ... presentational code overriding _layout
{% endblock %}

{% block footer %}
    ... presentational code overriding _layout
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the template code for `layout.twig` and `index.twig`?

Comment: Have you ruled out caching already, as in you're seeing an older version of the index that doesn't include your overrides?

Comment: I don't believe there are caching issues...updates to _layout are rendered fine.

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.5 or greater? If so, it has OpCache enabled by default which might explain what you're seeing that you can disable.

Comment: Thanks Brad but I'm running 5.4.10. I continue to look at this but cannot fathom where the issue is... I'm debating removing MAMP and reinstalling.