# Twig template not extending

Tags: templating

Folks:

I am having issue getting Twig to extend the template. The details:

- Craft installed fine.
- This is on a live server.
- The default Craft welcome page appears as normal so Twig must be
  working.
- When I try to pull up an entry with one of my own templates, Twig does
  not pull the content from the main Twig template. You should see the
  header info and have the css pulled and all the rest. If I strip
  everything out the template and leave some plain text I still see
  this in the browser:

  `{ % extends "_layouttest" % } { % block main % } This is the correct template alright! { % endblock % }`

I have done the following:

- Checked that I am not pulling the template directly. I am not. This
  is a proper URL for an entry I created in Craft.
- Dumped the cache.
- Checked the template locations from within the CP. All seems to be
  pointing in the correct direction. The fact that the right template
  is being pulled confirms this.
- Read through [this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11361/twig-code-showing-in-browser) and [this one](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5206/only-layout-template-being-rendered-in-local-environment). No joy.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't actually have a space between the `{` and `%` in your code, do you?

Comment: You have so got to be kidding me, right? Yes, that was the problem. And no, I am not a complete dunce (but it feels that way). ExpressionEngine tags worked in a similar fashion. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, cool. Posted it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a space between the `{` and `%` in your twig tags. That needs to be removed. :)